# QML/QT exe: Unable to execute the standalone application

Tags: qt, dll, qml, visual-studio-2019

I am not able to execute the exe outside visual studio 2019(even with dependent dlls(QT)).
The application runs only when I execute it through visual studio.
I have checked and added all the dependencies(dlls) but I am getting "QMLApplicationEngine failed to load component!".

We are trying to create a QML application, where I am passing the Qurl as follows:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated, &app, [url](QObject* obj, const QUrl& objUrl)
        {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);
```

It is getting built and is running perfectly fine in Visual Studio 2019. But when I am trying to deploy the same exe in some other system without Visual Studio, with QT/QML dlls, the exe is not running and is throwing the following error:

[image: Image1]

The error msg showing QMLApplicationEngine failed to load component:

```
QMLApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:14 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:12 module "QtQuick.Layouts" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:17 module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:6 module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
```

[image: Image2]

The error msg showing null connections to slots:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::mSegCTBone() to QMLManager::QSegCTBone()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::mSegCTLung() to QMLManager::QSegCTLung()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::mLength2D() to QMLManager::QLength2D()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::mAngle2D() to QMLManager::QAngle2D()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::mCircle2D() to QMLManager::QCircle2D()
QObject::connect: Cannot connect QMLManager::signalToEnableWaitBox() to (null)::mEnableWaitBox()
```

I have tried adding all QT/QML dlls, but in vain.

I am not able to figure out what I am missing or what I am doing wrong as to why the exe is not able to run.
It will be very helpful if anyone can help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You probably did not add ALL the necessary DLLs. Read this https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/windows-deployment.html

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager is on the money. Give `windeployqt` a go.